# Can't find input file libssh2.lib using pip install parallel-ssh

Tags: pip, python-3.11, parallel-ssh

I'm trying to install a python package on Windows 10 and am getting the following output from the command line. Error is being thrown while building the wheel for the dependency ssh2-python

```
  Building wheel for ssh2-python (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [38 lines of output]
      C:\Users\624463\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\extension.py:134: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'cython_compile_time_env', 'cython_directives'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\agent.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\channel.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\c_pkey.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\c_sftp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\c_ssh2.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\c_stat.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\error_codes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\fileinfo.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\knownhost.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\listener.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\pkey.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\publickey.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\session.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\sftp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\sftp_handle.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\statinfo.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      copying ssh2\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2
      running build_ext
      building 'ssh2.agent' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ssh2
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ilibssh2/include -IC:\Users\624463\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\624463\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.20348.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcssh2\agent.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ssh2\agent.obj
      agent.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:/usr/local/lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\624463\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\624463\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\624463\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.20348.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.20348.0\\um\x64" Ws2_32.lib libssh2.lib user32.lib libcrypto64MD.lib libssl64MD.lib zlibstatic.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_agent build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ssh2\agent.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\ssh2\agent.cp311-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ssh2\agent.cp311-win_amd64.lib
      LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libssh2.lib'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ssh2-python
  Running setup.py clean for ssh2-python
Failed to build ssh2-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ssh2-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm pretty sure I have the correct Visual Studio SDK/C++ tools so I'm unsure what exactly is missing to where it's missing the libssh2.lib file.  TYIA for any input and help